# OpenCPU Functions

Tags: r, web-services, opencpu

I am trying out the OpenCPU software for making R-based functions available as web services. So I created (for testing purposes) a function that takes TRUE/FALSE and returns one of two strings as a result.

I managed to get a web service running (in single-user mode, on my own computer). However, when I try to access that web service by POSTing, the return value isn't the result of the function, but is instead a bunch of urls:

```
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/stdout
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/source
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/console
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/info
/ocpu/tmp/x038e60b267/files/DESCRIPTION
```

The first url will return the result of my function call, which is nice. But isn't there a way to get the return value from the POST to be the result of the function call, rather than a bunch of URLs?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Doh! Yes, I was missing something obvious, which was putting /json on the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

This was trivial. If you append "/json" to the end of the URL, then it will return the result as Json.